# AssertionError: False is not true (Django version 1.8.3)

Tags: python, django

I have been trying to find out what's going on with the code i have created in django 1.8.3...When i am using django's test runner (and more specifically the command: `python manage.py test predsite`) i am always getting the same error message:

> File "C:\Users\dimitris\djangop\oursite\predsite\tests.py", line 117, in test_long_list
>        self.assertTrue('pagination' in response.content)
>   AssertionError: False is not true

Here is the code i've created in detail:
**OURSITE(PROJECT)>>PREDSITE(APP)>>MODELS.PY:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import os


def hashed_uploads_dirs(instance, filename):
    """Returns path with md5 hash as directory"""
    return os.path.join(instance.md5, filename)

class Datafile(models.Model):
    file_id = models.IntegerField(default=0, primary_key=True)
    datafile = models.FileField(upload_to='.')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1)
    md5 = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

**OURSITE>>PREDSITE>>VIEWS.PY**:

```
class FileListView(ListView):

   model = Datafile
   queryset = Datafile.objects.order_by('-file_id')
   context_object_name = "files"
   template_name = "index.html"
   paginate_by = 5


class FileAddView(FormView):

   form_class = DatafileForm
   success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
   template_name = "add.html"


   def form_valid(self, form):
      form.save(commit=True)
      messages.success(self.request, 'File uploaded!', fail_silently=True)
      return super(FileAddView, self).form_valid(form)


class FileAddHashedView(FormView):
     """This view hashes the file contents using md5"""

   form_class = DatafileForm
   success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
   template_name = "add.html"

   def form_valid(self, form):
    hash_value = hashlib.md5(form.files.get('datafile').read()).hexdigest()
    # form.save returns a new Datafile as instance
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    instance.md5 = hash_value
    instance.save()
    messages.success(
        self.request, 'File hashed and uploaded!', fail_silently=True)
    return super(FileAddHashedView, self).form_valid(form)
```

**OURSITE>>OURSITE>>URLS.PY**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
     url(r'^add/$', FileAddView.as_view(), name='datafile-add'),
     url(r'^add/files/$', FileListView.as_view(), name='home'),
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, datafile_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**OURSITE>>PREDSITE>>CONTEXT_PROCESSORS.PY**

```
from django.conf import settings


def static_root(request):
    """
    Adds static-root context variables to the context.

    """
    return {'STATIC_ROOT': settings.STATIC_ROOT}


def media_root(request):
   """
   Adds media-root context variables to the context.

   """
   return {'MEDIA_ROOT': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}
```

**OURSITE>>PREDSITE>>FORMS.PY**

```
class DatafileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Upload files with this form"""
    class Meta:
       model = Datafile
       exclude = ('md5',)
```

**OURSITE>>PREDSITE>>TESTS.PY** (I'm providing the section where the error occurs)

```
def test_long_list(self):
    """Get a paginated home page"""
    filename = "./file_{}.txt"
    for x in xrange(10):
        fb = Datafile(datafile=filename.format(x))
        fb.save()
    response = self.client.get(reverse('home'))
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    self.assertTrue('pagination' in response.content)
    self.assertEqual(
        len(response.context['files']),
        FileListView.paginate_by)
```

And the template that matters for now is the following:
**OURSITE>>TEMPLATES>>index.html**

```html
{% extends "basic.html" %}
{% load static %}


{% block page_title %}Home{% endblock %}


{% block content %}


<h1>The files</h1>


{% if files %}

<div class="panel">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Primary Key</th>
        <th>Filename</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for file in files %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ file.file_id }}</td>
        <td><a href="{% get_media_prefix %}{{ file.datafile }}">{{ file.datafile }}</a></td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>    
  </table>
</div>


{% if page_obj.has_other_pages %}
<div class="pagination-centered">
  <ul class="pagination">
    {% if paginator.has_previous %}
    <li class="arrow"><a href="?page={{ paginator.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
    {% else %}
    <li class="arrow unavailable"><a href="">&laquo;</a></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% for pg in paginator.page_range %}
      {% if page_obj.number == pg %}
        <li class="current"><a href="?page={{ pg }}">{{ pg }}</a></li>
      {% else %}
        <li><a href="?page={{ pg }}">{{ pg }}</a></li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if paginator.has_next %}
    <li class="arrow"><a href="?page={{ paginator.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a></li>
    {% else %}
    <li class="arrow unavailable"><a href="">&raquo;</a></li>
    {% endif %}
  </ul>
</div>
{% endif %}


{% else %}


  <!--                        -->
  <!-- Your database is empty -->
  <!--                        -->

<div class="panel">
  <p>No files uploaded yet &nbsp;&nbsp; :(</p>
  <p>(hint: Add a <a href="{% url 'datafile-add' %}" title="Add a file">file</a>)</p>
</div>

{% endif %}


{% endblock %}
```

Since it's obvious that there is a class called "pagination" in the above template, how is it possible that i am getting this error message while executing the test runner?

Thanks a lot, in advance!!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please consider posting a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get faster/better answers.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i will keep that in mind from now on!!

Answer (score 2):

This is because the `context` property of `response` returns the context variables, which is *not* the `html` code. Instead, you would test the `response.context['files']` list for the items you're looking for, if that were your goal.

Try using [assertContains](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/testing/#django.test.TestCase.assertContains) instead. The syntax from the docs suggests that you may want to add the following to your tests:

```
self.assertContains(response, 'pagination', html=True)
```

Comment: I think you are right as it concerns the source from where the error comes from...As it concerns the code you suggested instead it leads to this:**File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\test\testcases.py", line 358, in assertContains  msg_prefix + "Couldn't find %s in response" % text_repr> AssertionError: Couldn't find 'pagination' in response"**

Comment: I don't know what your data is looking for, so perhaps `if page_obj.has_other_pages` is not `true`?